# FwTemporaryTable

Tags: advpl

Oi, estou começando a programar agora em advpl e vi que o recomendado atualmente e o uso de tabelas temperarias com o FwTemporaryTable, porem tenho algumas duvidas, porque tentei fazer um código igual alguns exemplos que vi na net e na apostila do ADVPL avançado, e não deram certo.

Segue meu código:

```
user function tpmsb1()

Local aFields := {}
Local oTempTable
Local nI as numeric
Local cAlias as char
Local cQuery

Local cFields := " B1_FILIAL, B1_COD, B1_DESC, B1_USPRE, B1_TIPO, B1_LOCPAD, B1_UM "

//-------------------------
//Monta os campos da tabela
//-------------------------

aadd(aFields,{"B1_FILIAL","N",5,0})
aadd(aFields,{"B1_COD","N",5,1})
aadd(aFields,{"B1_DESC","C",15,0})
aadd(aFields,{"B1_USPRE","C",15,0})
aadd(aFields,{"B1_TIPO","C",2,1})
aadd(aFields,{"B1_LOCPAD","N",2,0})
aadd(aFields,{"B1_UM","C",2,0})

//------------------
//Criação do objeto
//------------------

cAlias := getNextAlias()

oTempTable := FWTemporaryTable():New( cAlias )

oTempTable:SetFields( aFields )

oTempTable:AddIndex("01", {"B1_COD"} )

//-----------------
//Criação da tabela
//-----------------

oTempTable:Create()

//  cAlias := oTempTable:GetRealName()

//  MsgInfo(RetSqlName("SB1"), 'Executando a copia dos registros da tabela: ')

    cQuery := "select"+ cFields +" from "+ RetSqlName("SB1")

// Deveria mas... não esta funcionando.
//  oTempTable:InsertIntoSelect( {"B1_FILIAL", "B1_COD", "B1_DESC", "B1_USPRE", "B1_TIPO", "B1_LOCPAD", "B1_UM"} , cAlias , { "B1_FILIAL", "B1_COD", "B1_DESC", "B1_USPRE", "B1_TIPO", "B1_LOCPAD", "B1_UM" } )

    MPSysOpenQuery(cQuery, 'TPMSB1')

    DbSelectArea('TPMSB1')

// Ate aqui, temos nossas infos nas variáveis, mas, são da tabela temporária, ou da SB1??...

        while TPMSB1->(!eof()) 
            for nI := 1 to FCount()

                VarInfo(FieldName(nI),FieldGet(ni)) //? 

            next DbSkip()
        EndDo

   //Exclui a tabela
   oTempTable:Delete()
return
```

Se alguém tiver uma leitura mais clara, ou videos sobre o assunto, aceito também como forma de ajuda \o

Comment: Arnon, o que não deu certo? Gerou algum error.log?

Comment: Oi Daniel, não teve nenhum "erro" aparente, porem, tenho como exemplo a função "oTempTable:InsertIntoSelect()" na apostila, e em alguns exemplos, vi o que ela devia fazer, e porque é importante, porem, no meu código ela não gera impacto nenhum. Sempre volta a primeira linha dos registros da SB1, oque me deixou na duvida se, só estou fazendo um select nela, ou realmente estou pegando as coisas na temporária.

Comment: Arnon, existem exemplos de uso dessa classe no Medium, dê uma olhada, espero que lhe ajude: https://medium.com/totvsdevelopers/insert-into-select-populando-tabela-tempor%C3%A1ria-1b3e1d1c93f e https://medium.com/totvsdevelopers/protheus-tabela-tempor%C3%A1ria-b2e955f43be4